# Error 500 when I turned DEBUG = False in Python Django

Tags: python, django

I've tried searching all across google and youtube but I still can't solve this. I tried to configure `ALLOWED_HOST` with my domains and also tested * parameter but still error 500. I'm new to django and I'm struggling with this. What's wrong with my settings.py?

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_heroku


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = '%6lp_p!%r$7t-2ql5hc5(r@)8u_fc+6@ugxcnz=h=b(fn#3$p9'


DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']




INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',


    'account.apps.AccountConfig',
    'voting.apps.VotingConfig',
    'administrator.apps.AdministratorConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'account.middleware.AccountCheckMiddleWare',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'e_voting.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['voting/templates', 'administrator/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'voting.context_processors.ElectionTitle'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'e_voting.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {
    #   You can use this :
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }

}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True



STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = []


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD='django.db.models.AutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.CustomUser'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['account.email_backend.EmailBackend']

ELECTION_TITLE_PATH = os.path.join(
    BASE_DIR, 'election_title.txt')  # Election Title File

SEND_OTP = True  # If you toggle this to False, Kindly use 0000 as your OTP

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: Is it the entire page giving this 500 http response, or when you try to open a certain file or image?

Comment: note you have STATICFILES_DIRS twice in your settings file, both times defined differently

Comment: it's the entire page, I can't access any of the links

Comment: when I run it on localhost it says

"GET /account/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145

Comment: remove "STATICFILES_DIRS = []" from settings file, change ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']

Comment: You'll need to get exact error traceback from the log first. You could try to trigger the problem in django development server `manage.py runserver` - the traceback is in console. If this doesn't work then configure django logger to some file (check web server service permissions first) and/or check nginx/apache/docker log output.

Comment: I removed the blank STATICFILES_DIRS and left only this STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]'] but still error 500

Comment: The errors at sent to my email is this -- Exception Type: ValueError at /account/
Exception Value: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'favicon.png'
Raised during: account.views.account_login
Request information:
USER: AnonymousUser

GET: No GET data

POST: No POST data

FILES: No FILES data

Comment: run this command in the terminal "python manage.py collectstatic", and then start runserver again

Comment: sorry for the late replies but I am busy

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution in this case is this:

Removing:

`STATICFILES_DIRS = []`

from settings.py and leaving:
`STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') ]`

Then make a backup of "staticfiles" folder if you have second thoughts about "collectstatic"

Running:
`python manage.py collectstatic`
after altering `STATICFILES_DIRS` in settings.py script and then typing "yes" to the warning prompt.

When you run the server again you shouldn't have this problem.